# python Link verification program

Tags: python

I was making python link verification program so that i can scrap all links in the given url and verify them.

I tried to use re module inside the for loop, and it turned out it is invalid syntax.

but i really can't think of other ways that could pull out all the links and check every one of them.. so i need help with it.

Here's the code:

```
import requests, bs4,webbrowser, re
from selenium import webdriver

url = str(input())
res = requests.get(url)

try:
    res.raise_for_status()
except Exception as err:
    print('There was a probelm with the first url: %s' % (err))

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
linkElems = soup.select('a')
hrefRegex = re.compile(r'^"http(s)?://.*?"')
mo = hrefRegex.search(linkElems)
for i in range (len(linkElems[i])
    mo = hrefRegex.search(linkElems[i])
    res = requests.get(mo.group())
        if res.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
                print('%s is broken link. Response: 404 "Not Found"' % (mo.group()))
```

And it says 'mo' part has invalid syntax, so i couldn't even test it... :(

And to verify means to make sure the link is not broken, which means they are valid urls so that we don't get 404 "Not Found" message from them.

Comment: What do you mean with verify? And what error message do you get?

Comment: @linusg I didn't get error message,since putting 'mo' inside the loop was invalid syntax. And to verify means to make sure the link is not broken, which means they are valid urls so that we don't get 404 "Not Found" message from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can grab the URLs using regex like:

```
urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', res.text)
```

`urls` will give you a list of URLs.

From there, you can verify the links if they're not broken by doing:

```
for url in urls:
    res = requests.get(url)
    if res.status_code != requests.codes.ok:
        print('{0} is a broken link. Response: 404 Not Found'.format(url))
```

Comment: Really appreciate your comment. I was dealing with noneType object while i was trying to get urls by using regex module. That was the problem why i kept getting this error message! AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @TonyAhn Glad I was of help.